# Collection element of type 'void *' is not an Objective-C object

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

Im trying to add the a gradient view to my background on for an iOS app.

Using the pod `UIColor+uiGradients` I am adding a GradientLayer to my background under `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIColor *startColor = [UIColor uig_emeraldWaterStartColor];
    UIColor *endColor = [UIColor uig_emeraldWaterEndColor];

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
    gradient.colors = @[(id)[startColor CGColor], (id)[endColor CGColor], nil];

    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];   
}
```

The error occurs on line `gradients.colors =  @[(id)[startColor CGColor], (id)[endColor CGColor], nil];`

error :

> Collection element of type 'void *' is not an Objective-C object.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the nil from the end of the array. You can't put nil in an Objective-C array, nor is it necessary in `@[]` literals. So:

```
gradient.colors = @[(id)[startColor CGColor], (id)[endColor CGColor]];
```

Comment: might want to clarify that when declaring an NSarray *this way* you don't use nil. `arrayWithObjects` still needs it. Tone is also a little... harsh?

Comment: When creating an array using `arrayWithObject:`, you are still not putting nil _into_ the array. You can _never_ put nil into an Objective-C NSArray. It isn't an object. Which is exactly what the error message said. - As for tone, maybe we come from different parts of the country (or different countries)!

Comment: Yes, exactly - but the answer might be confusing for noobs ;) It was the "Dude" bit that struck me as a little off - if not, no worries.